# Ajax loading a html page and having it fit the div size

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, sass

when I'm trying to load a page into a div using

```
$('#eg').load('american.html');
```

the div in question is the one that has "el__bg" from this template on codepen (I don't like copying from codepen but the guy instructed me to use it, and to load a page another dev at the company made into it, so I have very little faith that we can modify that page much)

I was hoping there was a way to trick the page being loading into thinking it's viewport size was the div's size?
I don't want to have to resort to using an iframe as one can't make them responsive with ease.

Any help or advice appreciated.